# How do i match up dates with the days in my application?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, calendar

This may seem a little basic but here is my issue.

```
function output_calendar($month, $year) {

    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $calendar.= '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr>';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td> </td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td style="width:14%;height:10%;">';
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div>'.$list_day.'</div>';

            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

        $calendar.= '</td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr>';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td> </td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';

    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar; 
}
```

Front End JS

```
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $(document).on('click', '#next', function() {
                            $("#main").empty();
                            if(display_month < 12) {
                            display_month++;
                            } else {
                            display_month = 1;
                            display_year++;
                            }
                            getCal(display_month, display_year);
                            $('#title').empty();
                            $('#title').html(months[display_month].concat(' ').concat(display_year));
                        });  
                        $(document).on('click', '#last', function() {
                            $("#main").empty();
                            if(display_month > 1) {
                            display_month--;
                            } else {
                            display_month = 12;
                            display_year--;
                            }
                            getCal(display_month, display_year);
                            $('#title').empty();
                            $('#title').html(months[display_month].concat(' ').concat(display_year));
                        }); 

                    });

                    // handles the click event, sends the query
                    function getCal(v1, v2) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "calGrab.php",
                       type: 'POST',
                       dataType: 'html',
                       data: content,
                        data: { 
                            "month": display_month, 
                            "year": display_year, 
                        },
                    }).done(function ( data ) {
                      $('#main').empty();
                      $('#main').append(data);
                    });
                    }
```

How do I go about correctly lining up the date with the associated day. For example, August starts on a Saturday for 2015. Are there any known techniques for this?

Please see prototype: http://calendar.conneraiken.com

Comment: you already have it. `date('w')` gives you day-of-week. so get day-of-week for `$month 1, $year`, and pad out your calendar using that starting point. e.g. if $month 1st is friday (w = 5), then you start your calendar in column 5.

Comment: I guess I dont understand why Im having the date issues in this prototype..


http://calendar.conneraiken.com

Answer (score 0):

You'd need 3 separate loops:

a) loop to pad calendar table with final days of previous month
b) loop to output current month
c) loop to pad calendar table with first days of next month

e.g.

```
 Su M  T   W  Th  F Sa
 28 29 30  1  2   3  4   // 1st week of current month
 a  a  a   b  b   b  b   // loops used
      ....               // full weeks in current month, all loop 'b'
    28 29 30  1   2  3   // final week of current month
    b  b   b  c   c  c   //  loops used
```

```
$first = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
$dow = date('w', $first);

# pad calendar for "end of last month"
echo '<tr>';
for($i = 0; $i < $dow; $i++) {
   echo '<td></td>';
}
... loop to output actual days in current month
... loop to pad final week with "next month" days to complete the row
```